# OsX Crontab having no effect

Tags: macos, cron, osx-mountain-lion, crontab

I am dynamically appending cron tasks to the user crontab

The tasks seem to be getting adde, `crontab -e` looks like:

```
*/10 * * * * /bin/sh /Users/john/Kiosk/app/content/update.sh
@reboot /usr/bin/open /Users/john/Kiosk/startup.command
```

Trouble is that it appears to be having no effect.

The content of startup.command:

```
cd /Users/john/Kiosk/app && /usr/bin/python -m SimpleHTTPServer &
sleep 5 && open http://localhost:8000
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use relative paths, buth full ones. Also with binaries.

Then, your line should be

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/<username>/Kiosk/app/content/update.sh
@reboot open /home/<username>/Kiosk/startup.command
```

Comment: Sure! It was a typo. Can also be `/bin/sh`, you can know it typing `which sh`.

Comment: Hmm, that's all changed, but the reboot is certainly still having no effect!

Comment: Have you tried changing `open` to `/bin/open` (or... `which open` result)?

Comment: `@reboot /usr/bin/open /Users/john/Kiosk/startup.command` is the command, which works when put straight into the terminal, but not on reboot

Comment: I have added more content into the question, hopefully this will assist you.

Comment: You need to give the full path to your python binary, because the PATH your user has is probably not the same one the cron user has.

Comment: Could it be that `@reboot` only works if the server is only launched on command line? Maybe you  can find some hints in this page: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work because

Comment: @NickW I've changed is to `/usr/bin/python` (informed by `whereis python`), no joy

Comment: Okay, so the server is being launched, it's just the browser not being opened

Comment: That's a step forward, what about a full path for the open command?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the open command away did the trick

```
@reboot yourscript.command
```

Answer (score 0):

The default path is `/usr/bin:/bin`, and tildes do work in the user crontab, so this should work:

```
*/10 * * * * bash ~/Kiosk/app/content/update.sh
```

Have you tried replacing `update.sh` with something like a say command for testing it?

`@reboot` works for me when restarting but not when logging out and back in. `@reboot open /test.txt` didn't work but `* * * * * open /test.txt` did.

You could also save a plist like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/simplehttpserver.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>simplehttpserver</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>python</string>
        <string>-m</string>
        <string>SimpleHTTPServer</string>
        <string>8000</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/john/Kiosk/app</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It can be loaded with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/simplehttpserver.plist` or by logging out and back in.